# C - How to make function return a pointer?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This function should return a pointer to the first occurrence of the largest int in an array without using the index operator. It can find and print the largest int, but how do I make it return a pointer? And how do I test if it was successful?

```
int *arr_first_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
    const int *k;
    int largest = 0;
    for (k = a; *k != '\0'; k++) {
        if (*k > largest) {
            largest = *k;
        } 
    }
    printf("%d\n", largest);
    return &largest;
}
```

Edit: size_t n is supposed to be used but I'm not sure how to include it.

Comment: Change largest to be `int *`, and instead of keeping the value in the array, keep a pointer inside the array.

Comment: why are you comparing int with char? `*k != '\0'` it could be just like this `for (k = a; *k ; k++)`

Comment: redundant parameter `size_t n`

Comment: Don't `return` `&largest` . `largest` is a local variable and will be released from stack as soon as function is terminated  . Thus , it will return an invalid or unauthorized ,memory address .

Comment: If your dataset contains zero, and the largest element have in position after that then it would not find the largest element.

Comment: @manetsus not sure how to include it in the function

Comment: Your code is returning `&largest`,  the address of a local variable -in the call frame which gets popped on return. This is typical undefined behavior. By enabling all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`) you'll get a warning (and might be able to use the debugger)

Comment: You should return  a pointer to the element within `a` which is the largest. not a copy of the value

Answer (score 2):

And another answer assuming:

1. `n` is length of array `a` (in terms of elements, not bytes)
2. You want to iterate through the whole array `a`

Then code is:

```
const int *arr_first_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
    const int *largest = a;
    while(n--) {
      if(*a>*largest)
        largest = a;
      a++;
    }
    printf("%d\n", *largest);
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: Surely you meant "NULL" :)

Comment: @StoryTeller Yes :P I've been writing too much in Java based environments recently :/

Comment: I see why you'd want a sanity check, than :)
I'll just add one more thing. Since `size_t` is unsigned (implementation-defined, but unsigned). The less than zero check is unnecessary.

Comment: @StoryTeller you're right there too. size_t is guaranteed positive. duh, what am I thinking? Just removed the line.

Answer (score 1):

In all functions `n` is assumed to be `>0`.

Just keep your logic, but instead of storing the max, store the index to the max, in order to return a pointer to the array at that index.

```
int *arr_first_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
  int i,l;
  for (l=i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
     if (a[i] > a[l]) l = i;
  return a+l;
}
```

**Edit** Pointer only version (based on comments) which does `n-1` iterations

```
const int *arr_first_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
    const int *most;
    for (most=a++ ; --n ; a++) if (*a > *most) most = a;
    return most;
}
```

And since I misread the question, a recursive bonus!

```
const int *arr_first_max_r(const int *most, const int *a, size_t n) {
    if (*a > *most) most = a;
    return --n ? arr_first_max_r(most, ++a, n) : most;
}
```

to be called like this

```
printf("Biggest int is : %d\n", *arr_first_max_r(a, a, n));
```

Comment: Usage of subscript operator is not allowed according to question.

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You detect the largest number like you did then run the same loop again to see where the number is then return that address. I also changed some data types from `int` to `const int` and I removed the 2nd parameter because you're checking for null characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const int *arr_first_max(const int *a) {
  const int *k;
  int largest=0;
  for (k = a; *k != '\0'; k++) {
    if (*k > largest){
      largest = *k;
    } 
  }
  for (k = a; *k != '\0'; k++) {
    if (*k == largest){
    return k;
    }
  }
}

int main(){
  int nums[6]={7,2,1,5,4,6};
  const int* y=arr_first_max(nums);
  printf("%d\n", *y);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming

- the function's signature is correct and complete (`arr_first_max` alludes that you search in an array for the first max element)
- and thus `int* a` is the pointer to the first element (i.e. equivalent to `int a[]` in a signature); I'll leave the `const` specifier in this case, though I think you could *omit/discard* it if the exercise permits that
- `size_t n` is the size of the array or, in other words, the number of elements in the array
- you want to return a pointer to largest element in the array without using the subscript `[]` operator

then this would be a solution

```
int *arr_first_max(const int *a, size_t n) {
    int *largest, *k;
    for (largest = k = a; (k - a) < n; k++)
        if (*k > *largest)
            largest = k;
    return largest;
}
```

That is because I quote from The C Programming Language:

> Pointer subtraction is also valid: if `p` and `q` point to elements of
>   the same array, and `p<q`, then `q-p+1` is the number of elements from
>   `p` to `q` inclusive.

Answer (score -1):

i won't guess what `size_t n` is for

```
int *arr_first_max( int *a, size_t n) {

  int *largest = a;
  while(*a){
      a++;
      if(*a>*largest) largest=a;
  }
  return largest;
}
```

Comment: The assumption that `a` is null-terminated isn't well founded. There's a reason a size parameter is passed.

Comment: I wonder if `size_t n` is size of `a` array. A null terminated int array seems pretty weird imho. Maybe what he's looking for is `while(n--)`? Keep iterating gone through whole array? who knows

Comment: @StoryTeller, i agree with you, but that what was posted in the question. i have no idea

Comment: @milevyo, the OP is still grappling with the basics of the language. It's better pedagogically to fix their example in a complete manner.

Comment: @StoryTeller, i have just to answer the question, and that what i did.

Comment: @milevyo Hehe PM: "Why did you do this?! This is crazy." Engineer: "It's in the specs!"

Comment: @milevyo OP said now he is not clear how to use `n` . So use it in a loop to iterate and stop checking for `'\0'` . For it to be precise answer :-)

Comment: @milevyo, your answer is brittle code, not something anybody (let alone the OP) should follow. Don't catch the OP a fish, teach them how to fish for themselves.

Comment: @MatthewGunn, i i am sory, i have rejected your edit. that because the way you changed the order of makes the code iterate one more time, and makes values of the first item compares to it self.

Comment: @milevyo you're right. sorry about that. I'm making so many errors I should get some sleep! Only thing... you should add the const qualifier in multiple places or drop it completely. As it is, my compiler rejects it.

Comment: @MatthewGunn, i hesitate at first , but when you suggested that, i doped const, thnk you any way for all